# How to iterate csv with Python and get only certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv -file structured like this:

```
Last Name;First Name;Start Date;End Date;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Example;Eva;;;1.1.2021;15.6.2021;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Here is some random information.;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
-------;Header;------- ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Index;Date;Time;Reading
0;10.4.2021;19:12:10;0,1;;;;;;
1;10.4.2021;19:07:14;;;;;;;;
2;10.4.2021;19:05:34;0,1;;;;;;
3;10.4.2021;19:05:32;0,1;;;;;;
4;10.4.2021;19:05:32;0,1;;;;;;
5;10.4.2021;19:05:31;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
-------;Header;------- ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Index;Date;Time;Reading
6;12.4.2021;19:12:10;0,1;;;;;;
7;12.4.2021;19:07:14;;;;;;;;
8;12.4.2021;19:05:34;0,1;;;;;;
9;12.4.2021;19:05:32;0,1;;;;;;
10;12.4.2021;19:05:32;0,1;;;;;;
11;12.4.2021;19:05:31;;;;;;;;
```

My goal is to get a clean dict out of the file with only the information I need. Let's say I want only name, dates and readings structured like this:

```
{
'last_name': 'Example', 
'first_name': 'Eva', 
'measurements': [{'date:': 'some_date', 'reading': 'some_reading'}]
}
```

How can I iterate through the columns and only get the ones I need? There are a lot of columns where the `Reading` field is nan. In my example this happens in the second and the last row, in both sections.

This is what I have tried so far to get the data I want from the csv:

```
df = (pd.read_csv(file,
                  sep='\s+',
                  skiprows=6,
                  index_col=0,
                  dtype='unicode'
                  )
       )
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Reading', 'Date', 'Time'])
print(df.keys())
print(len(df))
test_list = df.values.tolist()
print(test_list)
print(len(test_list))
```

This gives me result:

```
Index(['Reading', 'Date', 'Time'], dtype='object')
13520
[[nan, nan, nan], [nan, nan, nan], ...]
13520
```

So the list where I want to have the values is just a list of list of `nan`'s.

Comment: Since you have several (?) CSV files appended into one, this is not trivial using pandas csv reading. I suggest you keep each CSV as a separate file. I.e. one for names, one for readings, etc.

Comment: That is one CSV file I get, I can't affect it's structure. It has multiple sections where the column names (Index;Date;Time;Reading) are the same and I would need to get them all from the file.

Comment: @JonasByström Sorry, there was a mistake in the indexes in my example. They don't start over in different sections. The error is now fixed in my original post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read only certain rows and cells from csv with Python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68998745/how-to-read-only-certain-rows-and-cells-from-csv-with-python-pandas)

Comment: @mozway Maybe it does but as a beginner with handling CSV -files I wasn't sure how to handle the data. Thank you for trying to explain me the solution, this time I understood it more clearly with the example by Serge Ballesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a correctly formatted single csv file, but a text file containing multiple csv *fragments*. It will be easyer to use the lower level `csv` module than the high level pandas one:

```
with open(file) as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter=';')
    state = 0     # wait for the Last Name;First Name line
    for row in rd:
        if state == 0:
            if row[0].startswith('Last'):
                state = 1    # next line will contain last and first names
            continue
        if state == 1:
            # prepare the resul dictionary
            measurements = []
            d = {'last_name': row[0], 'first_name': row[1],
                 'measurements': measurements}
            state = 2    # wait for a header line
            continue
        if state == 2:
            if row[0] == 'Index':
                state = 3   # read data lines
            continue
        #  state is 3
        if row[0] == '':
            state = 2  // wait for next data bloc
        else:
            # process a data line
            measurements.append({'date': row[1], 'reading': row[3]})
```

This code only store the `date` and `reading` fields as text, but you will easily add more complex processing...

With your sample data it gives:

```
{'first_name': 'Eva',
 'last_name': 'Example',
 'measurements': [{'date': '10.4.2021', 'reading': '0,1'},
                  {'date': '10.4.2021', 'reading': ''},
                  {'date': '10.4.2021', 'reading': '0,1'},
                  {'date': '10.4.2021', 'reading': '0,1'},
                  {'date': '10.4.2021', 'reading': '0,1'},
                  {'date': '10.4.2021', 'reading': ''},
                  {'date': '12.4.2021', 'reading': '0,1'},
                  {'date': '12.4.2021', 'reading': ''},
                  {'date': '12.4.2021', 'reading': '0,1'},
                  {'date': '12.4.2021', 'reading': '0,1'},
                  {'date': '12.4.2021', 'reading': '0,1'},
                  {'date': '12.4.2021', 'reading': ''}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

This really looks like [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68998745/16343464), so just adapt [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68999159/16343464) ;)

#### header

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=';+', nrows=1).dropna(axis=1).loc[0].to_dict()
```

output:

```
{'Last Name': 'Example',
 'First Name': 'Eva',
 'Start Date': '1.1.2021',
 'End Date': '15.6.2021'}
```

#### data

```
df = (pd.read_csv('filename.csv',
                  sep=';',
                  skiprows=6,
                  index_col=0,
                  usecols=range(4),
                 )
        .drop(['Index', '-------', float('nan')], # get rid of extra headers
              errors='ignore')
     )
```

output:

```
            Date      Time Reading
Index                             
0      10.4.2021  19:12:10     0,1
1      10.4.2021  19:07:14     NaN
2      10.4.2021  19:05:34     0,1
3      10.4.2021  19:05:32     0,1
4      10.4.2021  19:05:32     0,1
5      10.4.2021  19:05:31     NaN
0      12.4.2021  19:12:10     0,1
1      12.4.2021  19:07:14     NaN
2      12.4.2021  19:05:34     0,1
3      12.4.2021  19:05:32     0,1
4      12.4.2021  19:05:32     0,1
5      12.4.2021  19:05:31     NaN
```